# Delete unattached internal polygons in single polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector

My shapefile is a single MultiPolygon (1 feature) which has some holes, within which there exist multiple parts of this polygon, remnants of vectorization. 
I need to eliminate those small as shown on the screenshots and cannot find a way to do so.

I work  in QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Dissolve, then extract only the large polygon to a new file - or select the large one, reverse selection and delete all the small polygons.

Comment: Thanks, but Dissolve does not work as the small areas are part of the only one and single feature within the Polygon (MultiPolygon)

Comment: Sorry, I meant "multipart to single" - as in, dissolve the multipartthingy into lots of singleparts ;-)

Comment: Ok, the native:multiparttosingleparts works as a charm to break it down. Then the rest is part of a tailor made pipeline to the needs :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS native:multiparttosingleparts works as a charm to break it down. Then the rest is part of a tailor made pipeline to one's needs. 
(credit to @Erik comment)